# CLion : how to change default code when I make new project?

Tags: clion

Everytime I create a new project in CLion, below code is written by default.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, I want to change that code.

How can I change these settings in CLion?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it hasn't been implemented. Feel free to comment or upvote the [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-5089.).

As a workaround, you may add a [live template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2017.1/live-templates.html) with the desired contents, and use it when appropriate.