# How to change the default main.cpp generated by CLion

Tags: c++, clion, jetbrains-ide

Every time I create a new project in CLion the default main.cpp is written like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
/**/

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

I searched everywhere but can't understand how to do it.

Comment: See [File templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/using-file-and-code-templates.html) from the CLion documentation. You may also want to read [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/11082165)

Comment: @Brian I tried using the templates but nothing changes, I don't know if I'm  making any mistake but my brain is exploding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CLion : how to change default code when I make new project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43567774/clion-how-to-change-default-code-when-i-make-new-project)